# Why is my code erroring?

Tags: android, android-studio, onclicklistener

While setting my on click listener for a particular button named convert When I write

The code gives a red underline at the space between View and v

I Am new to android studio and tried fixing this by searching on Google but no avail. Where and how am I wrong ?

**Edit 1:**  I sorted out the errors apparently it was a misplaced curly brace at the end of onCreate effectively terminating the onCreate before my actual code was executed.  However now it executes well except for one tiny little flaw it shows no output. What should I do?

Code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final EditText inputNum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputNum);
    final TextView octNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octNum);
    final TextView binNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octNum);
    final TextView hexNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octNum);
    final Button convert = (Button) findViewById(R.id.convert);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            convert.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int a = Integer.parseInt(inputNum.getText().toString());
                    String bin = Integer.toBinaryString(a);
                    String oct = Integer.toOctalString(a);
                    String hex = Integer.toHexString(a);
                    octNum.setText(oct);
                    binNum.setText(bin);
                    hexNum.setText(hex);
                }
            });


        }
    };
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

}
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve ? add a listener to that convert? what is your `convert`  `convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
               
            }
        });`

Comment: convert is the name (ID) of a button. Should I upload a bit more of the code ?

Comment: check my answer is that what you are looking for?

Comment: I have edited the question apparently the error was caused by a misplaced curly brace at the end of onCreate. But the code now executes but doesn't work. I dont get why

Comment: Executes but doesnt work means what? what do you expect ?what to you get?

Comment: @Charuka. I tried to get converted to binary hexadecimal and Octal strings for my entered decimal number but the TextViews remain set to their default values

Comment: your octNum  binNum hexNum views  points to same id -->octNum
`TextView hexNum = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.octNum);`

Comment: @Charuka. I corrected that but despite this The textviews always retain their default values (nothing) despite the settext

Comment: button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { your onClick listener seems wrong!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134380/discussion-between-suhrid-mulay-and-charuka).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //  handle your click event
            }
        });
```

**EDIT**

Push-buttons can be pressed, or clicked, by the user to perform an action!

A typical use of a push-button in an activity would be the following:
.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

         final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Perform action on click
             }
         });
     }
 }
```

However, **instead** of applying an `OnClickListener` to the button in your activity, you can assign a method to your button in the XML layout, using the `android:onClick`. <sub>***You are trying to achievesome kind of a thing and messed with setOnClickListener. Are you?***</sub>

Now, when a user clicks the button, the Android system calls the activity's `myClickMethod(View)`(that i created) method. In order for this to work, the method must be public and accept a View as its only parameter. For example:

```
     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="myClickMethod"
        android:text="button" />
```

and in code

```
public void myClickMethod(View view) {
     // Perform action 
 }
```

Comment: The errors with the on click have gone but the application still crashes at startup on the android VM. Saying something relating to FATAL EXCEPTION main

Comment: I am now testing the app on a phone to check if there is some fault with the AVD. Will update the question accordingly after the test is done

Answer (score 1):

U should provide a new instance of a onClickListener like this.

```
    convert.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Code here 
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to specify the parameter type when you call a method. The compiler will either figure it out on it's own or output an error. Currently, AndroidStudio is thinking you are trying to pass two parameters, "View" and "v", to the method and forgot the comma between them.

Replace the call with `convert.setOnClickListener(v)` and the error message will become clearer, i.e. setOnClickListener is not defined with a parameter of type View.